# Cannot find symbol "OnKeyListener"

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

What am I missing? I feel really silly having to post this but perhaps somebody else will see the (likely obvious) error that I am making.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class Primes extends Activity implements OnKeyListener
{
...
}
```

Error:

```
[javac] ...Primes.java:9: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol: class OnKeyListener
[javac] public class Primes extends Activity implements OnKeyListener
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a [nested interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html).

```
public class Primes extends Activity implements View.OnKeyListener
```